# react router dom v6 always redirect to login routes even user is authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, mern

I am trying to implement protected routes for orders router but even the user is authenticated it always redirect to login. I have used Navigate component from react-router-dom and I have passed the isAuth state for app.js to privateRoute.js component and I received that isAuth as prop in privateRoute.js but if I don't use the navigate component  then I get the isAuth true when user authenticates but it I used navigate component then it redirects to login routes before isAuth is set to true. Need help!!

```
    //app.js
    function App(props) {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
        isAuth: false,
        token: null,
        userId: null,
      });
      const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(true);
      useEffect(() => {
        if (window.location.href.includes("admin")) {
          setShowNav(false);
        }
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        const expiryDate = localStorage.getItem("expiryDate");
        if (!token || !expiryDate) {
          return;
        }
        const userId = localStorage.getItem("userId");
        const remainingMilliseconds =
          new Date(expiryDate).getTime() - new Date().getTime();
        setAuthState((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isAuth: true,
            token: token,
            userId: userId,
          };
        });
        setAutoLogout(remainingMilliseconds);
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      }, [authState.isAuth]);
    
      const handleUserCredentialsSubmission = (userData, setErrors) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("name", userData.name);
        formData.append("email", userData.email);
        formData.append("password", userData.password);
    
        fetch("http://localhost:3080/signup", { method: "POST", body: formData })
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
              if (res.status === 409) {
                throw new Error("Email address already exists!");
              } else {
                throw new Error("Creating a user failed!");
              }
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((resData) => {
            navigate("/login");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setErrors((prevState) => {
              return {
                ...prevState,
                signupError: err.message,
              };
            });
            throw new Error(err);
          });
      };
    
      const logoutHandler = () => {
        setAuthState((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isAuth: false,
            token: null,
          };
        });
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        localStorage.removeItem("userId");
        localStorage.removeItem("expiryDate");
        navigate("/login");
      };
    
      const setAutoLogout = (remainingTime) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          logoutHandler();
        }, remainingTime);
      };
    
      const handleUserlogin = (userData, setErrors, setUserCredentials) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("email", userData.email);
        formData.append("password", userData.password);
    
        fetch("http://localhost:3080/login", { method: "POST", body: formData })
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
              throw new Error("Invalid Email Address & Password");
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((resData) => {
            setAuthState((prevState) => {
              return {
                ...prevState,
                isAuth: true,
                token: resData.token,
                userId: resData.userId,
              };
            });
            localStorage.setItem("token", resData.token);
            localStorage.setItem("userId", resData.userId);
            const remainingMilliseconds = 60 * 60 * 1000;
            const expiryDate = new Date(
              new Date().getTime() + remainingMilliseconds
            );
            localStorage.setItem("expiryDate", expiryDate.toISOString());
            navigate("/");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setAuthState((prevState) => {
              return {
                ...prevState,
                isAuth: false,
                token: null,
                userId: null,
              };
            });
            setUserCredentials((prevState) => {
              return {
                ...prevState,
                email: "",
                password: "",
              };
            });
            setErrors((prevState) => {
              return {
                ...prevState,
                loginError: err.message,
              };
            });
            throw new Error(err);
          });
      };
    
      const handleAddToCart = (productId) => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3080/cart", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + authState.token,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            prodId: productId,
          }),
        })
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
              throw new Error("User does not Exists");
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((resData) => {
            navigate("/cart");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            throw new Error(err);
          });
      };
      console.log(authState.isAuth);
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          {showNav && (
            <Nav
              token={authState.token}
              isAuth={authState.isAuth}
              onLogout={logoutHandler}
            />
          )}
          {/* <Nav /> */}
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/product"
              element={
                <Product isAuth={authState.isAuth} AddToCart={handleAddToCart} />
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/product/:productId"
              element={
                <ProductDetails
                  {...props}
                  isAuth={authState.isAuth}
                  AddToCart={handleAddToCart}
                />
              }
            />
            <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart token={authState.token} />} />
            <Route
              path="/orders"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute {...authState}>
                  <Orders token={authState.token} />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/checkout"
              element={<Checkout token={authState.token} />}
            />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login onSingIn={handleUserlogin} />} />
            <Route
              path="/signup"
              element={<Signup onSignUp={handleUserCredentialsSubmission} />}
            />
            <Route path="/admin/*" element={<Admin />}>
              <Route
                path="product"
                element={<AddProduct token={authState.token} />}
              />
              <Route path="products" element={<AdminProducts Admin={!showNav} />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            {/* <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} /> */}
          </Routes>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;

    //privateRoute.js
    const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
      console.log(props.isAuth);
      if (!props.isAuth) {
        return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
      }
      return props.children;
    };

    export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `authState.isAuth` state's initial value looks to match the "unauthenticated" state, so when the app is initially loading/mounting and the user is on a protected route the `PrivateRoute` bounces them off it to the login route to authenticate.

Use an initial `authState.isAuth` value that isn't one of the confirmed/validated/verified authentication state values. In other words, anything ***other than*** `true` or `false`. Update the `PrivateRoute` component to check for this initial condition and conditionally render null or some loading indicator until the authentication status is confirm.

App

```
const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
  isAuth: undefined,
  token: null,
  userId: null,
});
```

privateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ isAuth }) => {
  if (isAuth === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return isAuth
    ? children
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

Note that you will need to explicitly set the `authState.isAuth` state for the unauthenticated logic paths, i.e. authentication fails, token expired, etc.

Comment: I have set isAuth to undefined but still its not working. It shows me the orders route but it does not redirect to login for unauthenticated user

Comment: @RohanRanaMagar I thought the issue was the code *always* redirecting to `"/login"`. Can you clarify what the issue *actually* is? Do you need a more concrete example of [route protection](/a/66289280/8690857)?

Comment: you are right. I always redirecting to "/login" router even the user is authenticated. I have set isAuth State to false initially and once the user is logged in it is set to true .Here is how I create private router                                                                             const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  console.log(props.isAuth);
  if (props.isAuth === undefined) {
    return <Loader />;
  }
  return props.isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

Comment: here is the github link https://github.com/Rohan-mgr/MERN-Online-Store

Comment: can you please have look the above github link and help me to solve the protected routes problem

Comment: @RohanRanaMagar I did take a look at your repo when you first posted it. Just took a look again now to see if I'd missed anything. The code there is still using an initial false `authState.isAuth` value and now it seems the `PrivateRoute` can never redirect to `"/login"` since if `isAuth === false` is true then the `Loading` component is rendered.

Comment: the problem is  authState.isAuth will never true coz isAuth is set to true after a api call so before setting the isAuth state to true the privateRouter component redirect to login and it is never set to true. Need the solution for this

Comment: @RohanRanaMagar That's the entire point of using an initial value that ***isn't*** true or false and waiting to render either the `children` or the `Navigate` component. If the initial `isAuth` state matches either of the "authenticated" or "unauthenticated" state then the `PrivateRoute` component is going to not wait until the auth status is confirmed. Don't start from an "unauthenticated" `false` state, start from an "I don't know the status" `undefined` state. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes it totally make sense and I have start with undefined but still it does not work?

Comment: It still redirecting me to login page

Comment: ` const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  if (props.isAuth === undefined) {
    <Loader />;
  }
  console.log(props.isAuth);

  return props?.isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}; `

Comment: @RohanRanaMagar Then it seems `props.isAuth` is always falsey for some reason. FWIW I am unable to reproduce the issue you describe. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-always-redirect-to-login-routes-even-user-is-authenticated-be31e8?file=/src/App.js) demo. If you navigate directly to `"/orders"` there's a 50% chance of already being authenticated, otherwise you can "log in" via the `"/login"` route. Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue you describe that we could inspect live? Feel free to fork from my sandbox.